# AngularJS - ui-grid - Data display issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am implementing http://ui-grid.info/ in my application.

I am populating the `grid` with `ajax call` like this :-

```
$scope.getGrid = function () {
     jq.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "getData",
                dataType: "html",
                traditional: true,            
                data: { columnDb: $scope.columnDb },
                success: function (data) {
        var dataObj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        ......
        $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.myData;  
     });        
}
```

There is a weird problem i am facing. on the above `function` call, i can see nothing in my HTML, But if i just `mouse scroll` on the `Grid` area the `data` gets displayed, even if i open `Inspect Element` in `Chrome`, the `data` gets displayed.

Any Idea How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does not lead to an Angular digest when the ajax call returns, and hence you don't see anything change in your on screen 'view'. So you can either:

1. Use `$http` for your ajax call
2. Add a `$scope.$apply()` to the callback function.

I would suggest using 1

Comment: Thanks Frnd...I gone with 2nd opt...!!